# Flask configuration handling via command line arguments?

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn

I'm trying to wrap my head around configuration handling in flask. It seems to have a lot built in so I suspect it already does what I want, but I haven't seen any examples of doing what I want.

Essentially I want to define config files for different environments (dev,prod,etc) and switch to them via command line.

So ultimately this is how I start the app:

```
gunicorn --log-level=debug --preload --worker-class gthread --workers 2 --bind :80 src.main:app
```

How can I pass an argument to that command that defines the config file my app uses? Right now I'm using configparser.ConfigParser() and hard-coding the path of a config file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flask configurations can be read from shell environments. Try setting values just like in the [CLI documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/cli/), just like the following:

```
export FLASK_DEBUG=1
```

Run the above command before the `gunicorn` command, and it should work like a charm.